# Normalize / Create a unit quaternion number / calculation using Python and Blender

Tags: python, mathematics, quaternion

I'm trying to work with quaternion math in Blender 2.82a and Python I need to normalize a quaternion number in Blender 2.82a using Python before I do calculations on it but I'm getting an error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Quaternion' and 'float' for the line
quat1_norm = quat1 / math.sqrt(ww**2 + ii**2 + jj**2 + kk**2)
```

The code below is:

```
import math
import mathutils
import numpy as np

new_angle_rad = np.deg2rad(10)
ww = np.cos(new_angle_rad/2)
ii = np.sin(new_angle_rad/2)*0
jj = np.sin(new_angle_rad/2)*1
kk = np.sin(new_angle_rad/2)*0

quat1 = mathutils.Quaternion((ww, ii, jj, kk))

#Normalize quaternion to length 1 (unit quaternion). 
quat1_norm = quat1 / math.sqrt(ww**2 + ii**2 + jj**2 + kk**2) 

print(ww,ii,jj,kk)
print(quat1)
```

I'm trying to convert Octave code to work in Python and Blender
https://octave.sourceforge.io/quaternion/function/@quaternion/unit.html

Here's the Octave math code I'm trying to convert.

```
Function File: qn = unit (q)

    Normalize quaternion to length 1 (unit quaternion).

              q = w + x*i + y*j + z*k
              unit (q) = q ./ sqrt (w.^2 + x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2)

Package: quaternion
```

I did try:

```
quat1_norm=mathutils.Quaternion.normalize(mathutils.Quaternion((1, 2, 3, 4)))
print(quat1_norm)
```

it comes back with **None**.

When a similar command is done in Octave I get this

```
unit(quaternion(1,2,3,4))
ans = 0.1826 + 0.3651i + 0.5477j + 0.7303k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done making and using the function below:

Original:

```
def normalize(v, tolerance=0.00001):
    mag2 = sum(n * n for n in v)
    if abs(mag2 - 1.0) > tolerance:
        mag = math.sqrt(mag2)
        v = tuple(n / mag for n in v)
    return np.array(v)
```

Updated Version using batFINGER suggestion: April 26 2020

```
def normalize(v, tolerance=0.00001):
    mag2 = sum(n * n for n in v)
    if mag2 > tolerance:
        mag = math.sqrt(mag2)
        v = tuple(n / mag for n in v)
    return np.array(v)
```

Or using the built in Function

```
import mathutils
quat1 = mathutils.Quaternion((1, 2, 3, 4))
quat1_norm = quat1.normalized()
print(quat1_norm)
```

Comment: Would edit to `if mag2 > tolerance:`  only zero length vectors are an issue.

Comment: Trying methods above on `Quaternion((0, 0, 0, 0))`  deliver a zero division  error, (0, 0, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0, 0).   Not sure why the zero quat result normalizes to x=1 whereas default (`Quaternion()`) is w=1.   If using numpy   no need to loop  `normalized_v = v / np.sqrt(np.sum(v ** 2))`  and check for all zeros.